# LibreOffice single quote

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have an error in Postgresql when I try to execute a simple insert statement.

After much trial and error I have discovered that it is the single quote around the text that is causing the trouble.
I am initialising the data in the table from a list in LibreOffice. In LibreOffice the single quote in the following statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.cluster 
   (name, description) 
VALUES
   (‘Mining‘, ‘Mines and sells the minerals‘);
```

I then copy the statement into pgadmin and executing the statement yields and error.

If I edit the statement in pgadmin by deleting the single quote and replacing it with a single quote (same button on the keyboard!) the single quote looks like this and the statement executes just fine:

```
INSERT INTO public.cluster
   (name, description) 
VALUES
   ('Media', 'Provides platforms for internet services');
```

My question is does anyone know why there is a different behaviour in which single quote is used by LibreOffice vs pgAdmin and how do I ensure the "correct" single quote is inserted by LibreOffice?

Comment: This is probably the auto-correct feature in LibreOffice to insert "typographic" quotes. Using a word processor like LibreOffice (or Word or even WordPad) to edit code is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it is better to use a plain text editor.

However it can be done with LibreOffice by turning off smart quotes and replacing all existing quotes.  Instructions are at http://earlruby.org/2011/08/how-to-turn-off-smart-quotes-in-libre-office-writer/.

Comment: This approach worked - the correct single quote that works when copied to PGAdminIII is U+0027

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice is an rich text editor, you might be pressing the same button on your keyboard but LibreOffice stores your character not plain as ascii or utf. So it's not the same character anymore.

In general you should use only plain editors or an IDE for typing any kind of code.

Comment: Is there  a way to identify which is the correct character and map it to the keyboard in LibreOffice?

Answer (score 0):

In my case its because of language used to parse document. Check language and charset you're using, it might be because of it.